# Agora voice call stops audio after 1 minute of lock screen

Tags: java, android, webrtc, agora.io, sleep-mode

I have implemented agora voice call in my application. Its working fine on older devices and tabs but on new devices after locking the screen for 1 minute the receiver cannot hear audio. I guess android system puts the app in sleep mode.

I have tried to use WAKE_LOCK to keep the app alive but no success. Can anyone help me in this? What i need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using **foreground service**. Now the systems prevents app from going into the sleep mode and voice issue is also resolved.

Comment: could you please provide sample for your workarround?